# How is it possible to extend docker php image with nodejs?

Tags: debian, docker

I'm trying to extend docker official php image with nodejs. The issue I run into is that apt refuses to find packages like wget, sudo, nodejs so that I can not install them. Is there anybody who knows the solution?

Comment: Show us your Dockerfile. You need to `apt-get update` before issuing `apt-get install wget nodejs`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The official PHP image [removes the APT lists after installing](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/5d49ba5861c0245da96132b011c8dbdad8c28188/5.6/fpm/Dockerfile#L31) it's required packages, probably to keep the resulting image layers small. Therefore you need to `apt-get update` first:

```
RUN    apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y wget nodejs --no-install-recommends \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

The last command in the chain removes the lists created by `apt-get update` again.